# MongoDB schema design -- Choose two collection approach or embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to design a simple application where in I have two entities Notebook and Note. So Notebook can contain multiple Notes.In RDBMS I could have two tables and have One to Many 
relationship between them. I am not sure in MongoDB whether I should not take a two collection 
approach or I should embed notes in Notebook collection. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a perfectly reasonable situation to use a single collection called Notebook, and each Notebook document contains embedded Notes. You can easily index on embedded documents.

If a Notebook document has a 'notes' key, and value is a list of notes:

```
{
    "notes": [
        {"created_on": Date(1343592000000), text: "A note."}
    ]
}

# create index
db.notebook.ensureIndex({"notes.created_on" : -1})
```

My opinion is to try and embed as much as possible, and then choose to reference another collection via an id as a second option when the reference needs to be to a more general set of data that is shared and might change. For instance, a collection of category documents which many other collections reference. And the category can be updated over time. But in your case, a note should always belong to a note book

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself what kind of queries you will need to run on it. The "by default" approach is to embed them, but there are cases (that will depend on how you plan on using them) where a more relational approach is applicable. So the simple answer is "probably, but you should probably think about it" :)